# how save and restore large amount of image or bitmap when Activity changed

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an activity that contain many bitmaps that dynamically have received from web an displayed.
but when app go to activity B and then return to main activity all bitmaps should be received again because of recreate of activity.
Is it possible to save all bitmaps by onSaveInstanceState and restore them at returning time?
what is the best way to preserve all UI at returning time if you know?

Answer (score 1):

If you load the images with an image handling library, such as [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), the images will be cached in memory for you and reloaded from the cache without any work required on your part. All your image handling can be done with a snippet as small as this.

```
Glide.with(context)
         .load(https://developer.android.com/static/images/android_logo.png)
         .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from this being a very lazy question I am going to answer you.

[Data Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

[Storing Bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap.html)

Those 2 link help you understand how android caches Files and Bitmaps

You can save the images in the cache directory or use an LRU cache to save them.

Good luck